# How to get USB information by using "lsusb -v" in ADB shell?

Tags: android, usb, adb, webcam, lsusb

I can use `lsusb -v` command to pull the data about a USB Webcam and I can see all supported formats and resolutions in Terminal (Linux).

But I am using an Android device too and I want to connect USB Webcam to that device and to see supported formats and resolutions in ADB shell. When I type `lsusb` in ADB shell, the command is getting some port information about USB. But I want more detailed information about USB, so I type `lsusb -v` to see all supported formats and resolutions in ADB shell. But this command getting same information as `lsusb` (just port information). But I want to see all supported formats and resolutions in ADB shell.

How can I get the supported formats and resolutions from Android device by using ADB shell?